# Using predict with svyglm

Tags: r, linear-regression, survey

I have found some odd behavior with `predict` and the `svyglm` object from the `survey` package. If your newdata in `predict` has a factor/character with one level it spits out error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

This error makes sense if I was putting a one level variable as the predictor for a model, but for newdata I don't see the problem.

With regular `glm` this works fine.

MRE:

```
library(survey)

data(api)

dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

svymodel <- svyglm(api00~sch.wide,design=dstrat)
# errors
predict(svymodel, data.frame(sch.wide=rep("No",10)))

regmodel <- glm(api00~sch.wide,data=apistrat)
# works
predict(regmodel,data.frame(sch.wide=rep("No",10)))
```

I find that it works if I hack the levels of the factor, but this shouldn't be necessary:

```
svymodel <- svyglm(api00~sch.wide,design=dstrat)

predict(svymodel, data.frame(sch.wide=factor(rep("No",10),
                                             levels = c("No","random phrase"))))
```

Am I misunderstanding something or is this an issue with the `survey` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't putting a factor in `newdata`; you're putting a character string in. You should put in a factor with the *same set of levels* as the factor used to fit the model (not some random phrase) -- that's the only way the design matrix makes sense.

```
predict(svymodel, data.frame(sch.wide=factor(rep("No",10),levels=c("No","Yes"))))
```

`predict.lm` recovers the factor levels from the fitted object (I don't remember this being around in 2002, but I might be wrong). You can use that approach to automate:

```
predict(svymodel, data.frame(sch.wide=factor(rep("No",10),levels=svymodel$xlevels$sch.wide)))
```

and I'll put that on the list of things to do for the package.

Comment: Thanks Professor Lumley.

Comment: And version 3.31-5, now building on r-forge, adds the use of `$xlevels` to `predict.svyglm`